# Best practices for Xamarin.Mac MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding

I'm developing a WPF desktop application that I'd also like to run on
Mac via Xamarin.Mac. I've taken great care to separate as much core
code as possible into a PCL, and keep the WPF-specific code as thin
as possible.

The UI architecture is MVVM. All of my viewmodels, implementing
`INotifyPropertyChanged`, in are in my core PCL. The WPF UI components
can then directly bind to those viewmodel properties.

**My question is: how can I use my "portable"
PCL viewmodels from the Xamarin.Mac side so that I can use Cocoa
databinding?**

The main problem appears to be that, in order to interact with Cocoa
databindings, the viewmodels must inherit from `NSObject`, use the
`Register` annotation to expose the properties, and use the
`WillChangeValue`/`DidChangeValue` methods for notifying observers. I
don't see a way to do this for the viewmodels inside the PCL, mainly
because I can't have them inherit from NSObject if those same classes
are to remain usable from the WPF side.

I'd like to avoid using frameworks such as MVVMCross or MVVMLight because they contain a lot of things that I don't need. However, if there's no other way I'm open to using them.

Answer (score 1):

The irony.... I'm at the same crossroads you've mentioned almost a year later.
I was able to accomplish this without using MVVMLight or MVVMCross.

In my ViewModelBase, I used the SetProperty API to inspect first to see if the value is different from it's previous value. If it is different, I use the **MACOS** complier definition to invoke WillChangeValue/DidChangeValue accordingly, followed by the RaisePropertyChanged for all other platforms. Obviously I used the **MACOS** compiler def to subclass NSObject.

I came upon this stackoverflow post looking for a way to bind the ICommand interface to a Xamarin.Mac button. Apparently it's harder than I thought.

I suppose I could peek at the MVVMCross repository to see how they've accomplished this task. 
Anyway, I'm sure by now you've solved your multi-pcl-MVVM dilemma. 
Do share if you've done anything different than my approach.