# How can I use my "portable" PCL viewmodels in my WPF and Xamarin.Mac (Cocoa) project?

Tags: c#, wpf, cocoa, data-binding, xamarin.mac

I have a WPF project **(already fully done)**. I'm going to make this project for mac. I would like to utilize my WPF project backend code as much as possible. But I couldn't find any option to reuse my WPF viewmodels in my Xamarin.Mac project.

The main problem appears to be that, in order to interact with Cocoa data bindings, the viewmodels must inherit from NSObject, use the Register annotation to expose the properties, and use the WillChangeValue/DidChangeValue methods for notifying observers. But in my WPF project, I used implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged** for the data binding if I'm not wrong.

Can anyone suggest how can I reuse my viewmodels efficiently? Any solution or idea would be good for me.

I got a question that almost asked by 3 years earlier. But couldn't get any specific solution idea. Please check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259540/best-practices-for-xamarin-mac-mvvm-pattern).

Comment: What about the other question did not work for you?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Actually I couldn't get him properly. What he has done for solving this problem. If you understand could you please explain a little bit more what he did?